# Python RegEx for exact matches of brackets

Tags: python, regex, string

I am trying to parse a string which is of the following format:

> text = "some random string <inAngle> <anotherInAngle> [-option text] [-anotherOption ] [-option (Y|N)]"

I want to split the string in three parts.

1. Just the "some random string"
2. Everything that is ONLY in angle brackets. I.E inAngle and anotherInAngle above.
3. Everything that is in square brackets.

If I use the RegEx

```
re.findall(r'\[(.+?)\]', text)
```

It gives everything I need within square brackets. If I use the same RegEx with angle brackets however,

```
re.findall(r'<(.+?)>', text)
```

It gives the text which is within angle bracket that are within square brackets too. So for example "text" from above which is within [-anotherOption]. I do not want that. The RegEx for angle bracket match should only return "inAngle" "anotherInAngle" from above.
What would be the RegEx for it?

Also how do I get only the first part i.e "some random string". This string can have 2 or 3 number of words

Comment: What would be your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply disregard everything between square brackets before searching for things in angle brackets:

```
interm = re.sub(r'\[(.*?)\]', '', text)
re.findall(r'<(.+?)>', interm)
```

outputs

```
['inAngle', 'anotherInAngle']
```

then for matching the first part, match everything up to `[` or `<`. Granted this wont work if a string is allowed to randomly have either of these symbols unclosed embedded in the first part:

```
re.findall(r'([^<\[]+)', text)[0]
```

outputs

```
some random string
```

Comment: Thank you all. all solutions are good, but I will go with Macmee's since its easier to read when put in the code I have :) . One more issue i have come across is that in somecases the angle bracket matches are preceded by a word. For example :     some random string -aWord <string> .  I want to get the -aWord part as well alongwith the "string" . How to get that ?

Answer (score 2):

Try if this regex would [capture](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) what you need

```
\s*([^><[\]]+\b)|\[([^]]*)]|<([^>]*)>
```

- `\s*` preceded by optional [whitespace](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html)
- `([^><[\]]+\b)` Group 1: Any [non](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) brackets until [\b](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) (remove if undesired)
- `|\[([^]]*)]` or Group 2: What's inside square brackets
- `|<([^>]*)>` or Group 3: What's inside angle brackets

[See demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/bC8pK1/2) (use "code generator" if needed)

Answer (score 0):

```
<(.+?)>(?![^\[]*\])|\[(.+?)\]|((?!\s+)[^\[\]<>]+)
```

You can simply use this `re.findall`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/hE4jH0/10